# Unrecognized option "areas" in NelmioApiDocBundle Symfony3.4

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, symfony-3.4, nelmioapidocbundle

I want to build an UI documentation with swagger for my Restful API. this is the offitial documentation for that https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/NelmioApiDocBundle/index.html
But i got this error `Unrecognized option "areas" under "nelmio_api_doc"`

```
#routing.yml

app.swagger_ui:
    path: vyndteam/api/doc/{areas}
    methods: GET
    defaults: { _controller: nelmio_api_doc.controller.swagger_ui }

#config.yml

nelmio_api_doc:
    areas:
        default:
            path_patterns: [^/api]
            host_patterns: [api\.]
        business:
            path_patterns: [^/business]
        admin:
            path_paterns: [^/admin]
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You must check the version of the installed bundle "nelmio_api_doc"
the documentation is valid for version 3

Comment: I'm using  version 3.2.1

Comment: You can see the full configuration bundle with this command
bin/console config:dump-reference NelmioApiDocBundle

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
 path: vyndteam/api/doc/{area}
```